# Abstract algebra - rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a set $\{x+yi : x,y \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\}$ and I want to show that this set is a ring but instead of a direct approach,I would like to find some well known ring and show that this is its subring.Can someone suggest what ring that would be?

Comment: I tried C but I don't think that it's working.

Comment: It's certainly not a subring of $\Bbb C$, which has no elements of order $2$ (under $+$), whereas the given ring has $3$ elements of that order.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: You might be better off showing that it's a quotient than a subring. $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x]$?

I should also point out that your potential ring is quite small, so brute force would be a pretty reasonable way to do this in this case.

Comment: This argument is particularly nice in that one gets nearly for free that the ring in the question is a field, hence the unique field of order $2^2 = 4$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** There's a natural ring monomorphism $\Bbb C \to M(2, \Bbb R)$ given by
$$a + b i \mapsto \pmatrix{a & -b \\ b & a}.$$ Can you construct an analogous homomorphism for the ring in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative hint: Show $R[x]/I[\alpha] \cong (R/I)[\alpha]$ by finding the kernel of the homomorphism $\phi: R[\alpha] \to (R/I)[\alpha]$ given by:

$\phi(f(\alpha)) = [\pi(f)](\alpha)$, where $\pi: R \to R/I$ is given by $\pi(r) = r + I$, so that if:

$f(\alpha) = c_0 + c_1\alpha +\cdots + c_k\alpha^k$, then $\pi(f)(\alpha) = (c_0 + I) + (c_1 + I)\alpha + \cdots + (c_k + I)\alpha^k$.

(note: the $0$-element in $(R/I)[\alpha]$ is $I + I\alpha + \cdots + I\alpha^k + \cdots = I$).